# Wrong amount of messages counted in Mail

Tags: mail.app

I have an issue in Mail. The count of married mails is wrong:
[image]

I have 6 marked but the count say 7. **How to fix that?**

Comment: Have you checked all the folders?

Comment: Yes I did. If I look online on outlook.com its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Quit **Mail** if it’s open.
2. In `~/Library/Mail/V7/MailData`, delete any file that begins with “**Envelope Index**,” such as Envelope Index or Envelope Index-shm.
3. Your home **Library** folder is hidden by default. To display it, choose **Finder** > “**Go to Folder**” and then enter “`~/Library.`”
4. Open **Mail**.
5. Mail creates new Envelope Index files. This process may take a few minutes, depending on how many messages Mail is reindexing.

It will fix your issue.

Comment: Perfect thank you, this problem is fixed. But now I have an mail in drafts which can not be deleted. Do you also have a tip for this?

Comment: Select the Draft folder. Not the top Drafts folder but the specific draft folder for the specific account. And Under Mailbox in the Menu bar, select Rebuild.